# How to check if remote-signer is working as expected?

Tags: transactions, baker, remote-signer

How do I know that remote-signer socket started is working expected and accepting signing requests from my baker server without actually sending a transfer transaction.

Right now I just do a transfer `.00005` from `<key1>` to `<key2>` just to test if remote-signer setup is working.

Is there any other way like any transaction that require signing but don't require transfer of tz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just prefer to do this...it's a direct request to sign data without any possibility of forgetting to add the `--dry-run` flag.

`tezos-client sign bytes 0x03 for <tz alias or tz address>`

Here `0x03` is just any old random number. You could put any hex value here. If the remote signer is working you'll get back a message like:

`Signature: sigPab0p1MdqojAaNTvASSvLo4ULEujfNFurF71EdoruABoPLLwmSxEDJf4NfQx8nJi3ncjfMEJbiWojTDXDUB8wNF5fgFIbA`

Answer (score 6):

I figured out that you can use the `--dry-run` option in the `transfer` statement so that node will send transaction to remote-signer to sign, and you can check the remote-signer logs to see if everything is working fine or not.

`--dry-run` will not actually send the transaction to the network.

Comment: Note that the --dry-run (or -D) options have to appear at the very end of the command.. a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use Kiln. Kiln monitors your baker and will notify you if you miss any baking or endorsement opportunities (which will indicate that the signer is down).

It can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor).

Comment: That is good for monitoring but i don't want to wait for my baking or endorsement operation to know if my setup is working or not, and then miss my baking/endorsement if the setup was not working. I want to know before my baking/endorsement operation.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way. OP asked how to test that `signer` is working and this software will not do so.

Comment: Not directly no, but indirectly ‍♂️ Just trying to help. But seems like the --dry-run is a decent approach 